# Looking for a good reliable way to compare two very simple "images"

Tags: c#, image

I am currently playing around with a text - recognition class for an Android app I am developing.

Note: when I say "image", I actually mean 32 rows of 32bits, illustrated here as it looks in memory:

```
.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  . 
.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  # 
.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  # 
.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  #  #  #  #  #  .  #  # 
.  .  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  #  #  .  .  .  .  #  #  #  .  .  .  #  # 
.  .  #  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  #  #  #  .  .  .  .  #  #  .  .  .  #  # 
.  .  #  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  #  #  #  .  .  .  .  #  #  #  #  #  #  # 
.  .  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  #  #  #  #  #  # 
.  .  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  #  #  #  #  . 
.  .  #  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
.  .  #  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
.  .  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  #  #  .  .  .  #  #  #  .  .  .  .  . 
.  .  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  #  #  #  #  .  #  #  .  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  .  .  .  .  . 
.  .  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  .  #  #  #  .  .  .  .  . 
.  .  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  #  #  .  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
.  .  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
.  .  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
.  #  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
.  #  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
.  #  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
.  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
.  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
.  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  #  #  #  #  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
.  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
.  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
.  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  #  #  #  #  #  .  .  #  #  #  #  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
#  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  #  #  #  .  .  .  .  #  .  .  .  #  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
#  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  #  #  #  .  .  .  #  #  #  .  .  .  #  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  . 
#  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  #  #  .  .  #  #  #  #  .  .  .  #  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  . 
#  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  #  #  #  .  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  #  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  . 
#  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  #  #  #  #  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
#  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  #  #  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
```

Here is the process (simplified)

1. Get the drawing that the user makes, as a set of points.
2. Take the points, connect them together and normalise them to build a 32 x 32 pixel "image". (Normalise, as in compress into a 32 x 32 formation).
3. Compare said "image" to a range of stock "images" and determine the similarities - if the highest similarity is above a certain threshold, we can determine that the image is similar enough to pass the test. It's basically a pixel x pixel comparison.

However, the values I am getting do not vary much - I think that the large amount of whitespace is throwing the values off... Also an image may look similar but if it is offset by a few pixels relative to the other, it will not get many valid pixel comparisons.

For example, a human can see that, compared to this image:

```
.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  . 
.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  # 
.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  # 
.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  #  #  #  #  #  .  #  # 
.  .  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  #  #  .  .  .  .  #  #  #  .  .  .  #  # 
.  .  #  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  #  #  #  .  .  .  .  #  #  .  .  .  #  # 
.  .  #  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  #  #  #  .  .  .  .  #  #  #  #  #  #  # 
.  .  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  #  #  #  #  #  # 
.  .  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  #  #  #  #  . 
.  .  #  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
.  .  #  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
.  .  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  #  #  .  .  .  #  #  #  .  .  .  .  . 
.  .  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  #  #  #  #  .  #  #  .  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  .  .  .  .  . 
.  .  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  .  #  #  #  .  .  .  .  . 
.  .  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  #  #  .  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
.  .  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
.  .  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
.  #  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
.  #  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
.  #  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
.  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
.  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
.  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  #  #  #  #  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
.  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
.  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
.  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  #  #  #  #  #  .  .  #  #  #  #  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
#  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  #  #  #  .  .  .  .  #  .  .  .  #  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
#  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  #  #  #  .  .  .  #  #  #  .  .  .  #  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  . 
#  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  #  #  .  .  #  #  #  #  .  .  .  #  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  . 
#  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  #  #  #  .  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  #  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  . 
#  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  #  #  #  #  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
#  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  #  #  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
```

This one is very similar (similarity around 0.82)

```
#  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  . 
#  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  #  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  # 
#  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  #  #  #  .  .  .  .  #  #  #  #  #  .  #  #  # 
#  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  #  #  #  .  .  .  .  #  #  #  .  .  .  .  #  # 
#  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  #  #  .  .  .  .  #  #  #  .  .  .  .  #  # 
#  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  #  #  .  .  .  .  #  #  #  .  .  .  .  #  # 
#  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  #  #  #  .  .  #  #  # 
#  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  #  #  #  #  #  #  # 
#  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  #  #  #  #  #  #  . 
#  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
#  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
#  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
#  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  . 
#  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  . 
#  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  #  #  #  .  .  .  .  #  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
#  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
#  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
#  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
#  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
#  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  #  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
#  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  #  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
#  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  #  #  #  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
#  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
#  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  .  #  #  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
#  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  #  #  #  .  .  #  #  .  .  .  #  #  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  . 
#  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  #  #  #  .  .  .  #  #  .  .  .  #  #  #  #  #  .  .  .  .  . 
#  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  #  #  .  .  .  .  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  #  #  #  .  .  .  .  . 
#  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  #  #  #  .  .  .  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  #  #  .  .  .  .  . 
#  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  #  #  #  #  .  .  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
#  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
#  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  #  #  #  #  #  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  . 
#  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  #  #  #  #  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
```

And this one is very different: (similarity around 0.7)

```
.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
```

I would appreciate very much if someone could point me towards a better way of comparing the two "images".

Perhaps I need to reconsider the conversion of points to an image, as I do the following:

1. Take the points
2. Add points around them (to simulate line thickness)
3. Add them all into the image data, lerping between points to connect the gaps.

Comment: What if you compare density of the "non-points" on a per-row basis maybe?

Comment: I was thinking about that, there must be a relationship between the % similarity and the % of the row that contains blank bits?